# primes represented integrally by a homogeneous cubic form

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Expired by this question [Show determinant of matrix is non-zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/327884/show-determinant-of-matrix-is-non-zero) I am moved to ask:

Given integers $a,b,c,$ and cubic form
$$ f(a,b,c) = a^3+2 b^3-6 a b c+4 c^3 = \left|\begin{bmatrix} a & 2c & 2b\\b & a & 2c\\ c & b & a\end{bmatrix}\right|,  $$ 
what primes $p$ can be integrally represented as
$$  p = f(a,b,c)? $$

I think it is $3,$ all primes $p \equiv 2 \pmod 3,$ and all $p = u^2 + 27 v^2$ in integers, but not any $q = 4 u^2 + 2 u v + 7 v^2.$ I checked for $p < 10000.$

Note that, if $-p$ is represented, so is $p.$

Although it does not finish things, note that if $f$ integrally represents both $m,n$ then it represents $mn.$ That is because $f(a,b,c) = \det(aI + b X + c X^2),$ where
$$ X = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 2\\1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}.  $$ Then $X^3 = 2 I$ and $X^4 = 2 X.$

I once asked a guy at MSRI about pretty much the same problem, only instead of the important polynomial being $\lambda^3 - 2$ it was $\lambda^3 - \lambda^2 - \lambda - 1.$ The phrase norm forms came up, and he laughed at me.

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

```
   p           a           b           c
   2           0           1           0
   3          -1           0           1
   5           1           0           1
  11          -1           1           1
  17          -1          -1           2
  23           1           1           2
  29          -3          10          -6
  31          -1          26         -20
  41           1          -2           2
  43           1          -1           2
  47          -1           4          -2
  53           1          -4           3
  59           1           3          -2
  71          -1           2           2
  83           3           1           3
  89           1           2           3
 101           3          -7           4
 107          -1           0           3
 109           1         -12           9
 113           1           4           2
 127          -1          16         -12
 131           3           3          -1
 137          -3           1           3
 149           1           4          -1
 157          -1           5          -2
 167          -3           3           2
 173          -3           7          -3
 179           1         -31          24
 191          -1          -2           4
 197           5           2          -1
 223           1           5           2
 227           3          -2           3
 229          -1          -1           4
 233           1           5          -3
 239           1           3           4
 251          -1          -4           5
 257           1           0           4
 263           3           4          -3
 269          -1           9          -6
 277           1           5          -1
 281          -1           1           4
 283          -1           8          -5
 293           1          -9           7
 307          -1           4           3
 311           3           3           5
 317          -3           5           1
 347           3         -12           8
 353           3          -1           4
 359          -5          23         -15
 383          -5          28         -19
 389          -3           2           4
 397           1           7          -5
 401           1          -5           5
 419           3           6           5
 431           1          -7           6
 433          -1          -5           6
 439           3           1           5
 443           3          -4           4
 449           1           8          -6
 457           1           2           5
 461           5           4          -2
 467          -1          -1           5
 479          -1           4           4
 491           3          18         -16
 499          -1           0           5
 503           5           3           6
 509           1           4           5
 521           5           5          -1
 557          -1          89         -70
 563           3           6          -1
 569          -1           7          -2
 587           3           4           6
 593          -7           2           5
 599           1           7          -4
 601           1         -22          17
 617          -5         -59          50
 641           3          23         -20
 643          -1           3           5
 647          -1          14         -10
 653           1          16         -13
 659           3         -10           7
 677          -1         -11          10
 683          -5           5           3
 691           3          -2           5
 701          -1          -3           6
 719           5           5          -4
 727           3          -5           5
 733           3           9          -8
 739           1           7          -2
 743           3          -3           5
 761           1         -14          11
 773           5          -1           5
 797          -3           3           5
 809           1           2           6
 811           1           3           6
 821           3           7           6
 827          -1          11          -7
 839          -3           5           4
 857          -9           5           4
 863          -1           0           6
 881           1          -4           6
 887           7           3           7
 911          -1          -5           7
 919          -1           7           3
 929           9           2          -2
 941           9           3          -1
 947          -3           1           6
 953          -7          26         -16
 971          -1           8          -1
 977           1           7           5
 983           3           7          -3
 997           3         -11           8
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Comment: Expired or inspired? :)

Comment: @Amzoti, I think expired gives the more accurate feel.

Comment: I can't tell you how many times I've been there! :) + 1 for a very interesting question!

Comment: Is there a path to go from $p|f(a,b,c)$ for some $a,b,c$ to $p = f(a,b,c)$ for some $a,b,c$?

Comment: @Sanchez, always possible. The situations I know where that argument works are quadratic forms rather than cubic.

Comment: @Will Jagy, so do you mean always possible or always impossible? I've also seen that for quadratic forms but am uncertain about forms of higher degree. The divisibility problem seems to be quite tractable here.

Comment: @Sanchez, I meant your idea could work. Not sure how to do it myself.

Comment: This would be a consequence of $\Bbb Q(\zeta_3, \sqrt[3]2)$ being the ray class field of modulus $(6)$ for $\Bbb Q(\zeta_3)$ (which is not hard to check with norms), along with the fact that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$ has class number $1$ (which means that $p$ divides some $f(a,b,c)$ if and only if $p$ is represented by $f$). I don't see an easy proof of that class number statement.

Comment: @mercio, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The discriminant of $\Bbb Q \subset \Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$ is $-108$, and the Minkowski bound for this extension is $\frac {3!}{3^3} \frac 4 \pi \sqrt {108} \approx 2.940$.
So to prove that this number field has class number $1$ we only need to find a way to represent $2$, and $2$ is indeed represented by $(0,1,0)$.
Thus $p$ is represented by this norm form if and only if the ideal $(p)$ has an ideal factor of norm $p$, which happens if and only if $2$ is a cube modulo $p$.

If $p \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ then any nonzero element of $\Bbb F_p$ has one cube root in $\Bbb F_p$ and two cube roots in $\Bbb F_p^2$, so $2$ is a cube modulo $p$.

If $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ then $(p)$ splits in $\Bbb Q(\zeta_3)$, and $2$ is a cube if and only it further splits in $\Bbb Q(\zeta_3,\sqrt[3]2)$. Since $\Bbb Q(\zeta_3) \subset \Bbb Q(\zeta_3,\sqrt[3]2)$ is an abelian extension, it is a ray class field for some modulus $\mathfrak m$ of $\Bbb Q(\zeta_3)$.

Working modulo $6$, we have $(a+b\zeta_3)^3 = (a^3+b^3) - 3ab^2+3ab(a-b)\zeta_3 = a^3 + b^3-3ab^2 \in \Bbb Z/6 \Bbb Z$, and thus for any $a,b,c \in \Bbb Z[\zeta_3]$, $a^3+2b^3+4c^3-6abc = a^3+2b^3+4c^3 \in \Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$. So, norms that are coprime to $6$ are units ($\pm 1$) modulo $6$. So $\Bbb Q(\zeta_3,\sqrt[3]2)$ is an extension of the ray class field of modulus $(6)$ for $\Bbb Q(\zeta_3)$.

On the other hand, $G = (\Bbb Z[\zeta_3]/(6))^*/\langle \overline{\zeta_6} \rangle$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/3 \Bbb Z$, which is the Galois group of the extension $\Bbb Q(\zeta_3) \subset \Bbb Q(\zeta_3,\sqrt[3]2)$, so $\mathfrak m = (6)$, and $2$ is a cube modulo $p$ if and onlt if $p \equiv 2 \mod 3$ or $p = a^2-ab+b^2$ where $a+\zeta_3 b$ is congruent modulo $6$ to one of $\{1,1+\zeta_3,\zeta_3,-1,-1- \zeta_3,- \zeta_3\}$.

Each element of $G$ (modulo complex conjugation) corresponds to a class of primitive binary quadratic forms of discriminant $-108$, or a corresponding lattice class (modulo multiplication by a unit and complex conjugation) whose endomorphism ring is $\Bbb Z[3\sqrt{-3}]$:

$\Lambda = \langle 1, 3\sqrt{-3} \rangle$ is a lattice corresponding to the neutral element of $G$ : it contains $(6)$ and the numbers coprime with $(6)$ it meets all fall in the neutral class.
while $\Lambda = \langle 2, \frac {1+3\sqrt{-3}}2 \rangle$ corresponds to the other two classes : it contains $(6)$ and the numbers coprime with $(6)$ it meets all fall in the other two classes.

So if $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, then $p$ is represented either as $a^2 + 27b^2$ (when $2$ is a cube) or as $4u^2 \pm 2uv + 7v^2$ (when $2$ is not a cube), and never both at the same time.

Comment: Minor comment: the criterion in the first paragraph, that $p$ is a norm iff it is not prime in the cubic field, requires noting that $-1$ is itself a norm so that there is no need to distinguish between $-p$ or $p$ being a norm; they both are or both aren't. If $-1$ is not a norm in a quadratic field, for instance, then $-p$ may be a norm of some algebraic integer while $p$ is not.

Comment: @KCd and mercio, Thank you. I just posted the original question as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336191/more-primes-and-cubic-forms but his time I put the source (Hudson and Williams) I should have posted with this question. The area where I would enjoy additional tutoring is "Thus $p$ is represented by this norm form if and only if the ideal $(p)$ is not prime in this extension"

Comment: @WillJagy : it goes along these lines : there is an element of norm $p$, iff. there is a principal ideal of norm $p$, iff. (class number $1$) there is an ideal of norm $p$ (which necessarily contains the ideal $(p)$ of norm $p^3$), iff. there is a factorisation $(p) = (\mathfrak P_1)(\mathfrak P_2)$ with $N(\mathfrak P_1) = p$, iff. $X^3-2$ has a linear factor modulo $p$, iff. $2$ is a cube modulo $p$

Comment: @mercio, thank you. I simply never studied algebraic number theory, but in the natural course of things made up some problems where that is the method of choice, some still open.