# How would you show that $(\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt[3]{2}), +, \cdot)$ is a field? (Linear Algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

Is $(\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt[3]{2}), +, \cdot)$ a field ?
I came across this question while doing homework, but it was unlike any other problem I faced.
For instance, how would one show that :
    $(a+b\sqrt[3]{2})\cdot(c+d \sqrt[3]{2})$ belongs to              $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt[3]{2})$.

Thank you

Comment: What happened when you attempted to multiply out the expression $(a+b\sqrt[3]{2})\cdot(c+d \sqrt[3]{2})$? Did you get stuck or lost?

Comment: You should clarify whether by $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$ you mean $\{a+b\sqrt[3]2; a,b\in\mathbb Q\}$ or $\{a+b\sqrt[3]2+c\sqrt[3]{2^2}; a,b,c\in\mathbb Q\}$. The former seems closer to your attempt, the latter is the usual definition.

Comment: Some related posts:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533655/is-mathbbq%CE%B1-ab%CE%B1c%CE%B12-a-b-c-%E2%88%88-mathbbq-with-%CE%B1-sqrt32-a-fiel
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294993/show-mathbbq-sqrt32-is-a-field-by-rationalizing 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1298030/multiplicative-inverse-element-in-mathbbq-sqrt32
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1717974/prove-that-mathbb-q-sqrt32-is-a-field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is by definition, the smallest field containing $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt[3]{2}$.

Thus, there is nothing to prove.

The fact that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ is a field may need further proof. Note the difference between round bracket and square bracket!