# how to show that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ is a field? (by elementary means)

Tags: diophantine-equations, cubics

To be very concrete, I want to show that every element of the form 
$1/(p+qx+rx^2)$ where $x=\sqrt[3]{2}$ where $p,q,r$ are rationals can be written in the form $a+bx+cx^2$ where again $a,b,c$ are integers. 
Clearly, it is enough to show that certain 3x3 matrix with coefficients involving $p,q,r$ has nonzero determinant. However, I cannot show why it cannot be zero for rational values of $p,q,r$. Any simple way to do this?

Comment: Assume $p+qx+rx^2 \neq 0$ then look to see if $(p+qx+rx^2)(a+bx+cx^2)-1=0$ is soluble.

Comment: That's what I did. By taking the determinant, you get an expression for $p,q,r$. I want to show that it cannot be zero for rational values of $p,q,r$.

Comment: Simpler, $\,x^3\!-\!2\,$ is irreducible over $\,\Bbb Q,\,$ so $\,\deg f < 3\,\Rightarrow\, (f,x^3\!-\!2) = 1,\,$ so, by Bezout's identity for the gcd we get $\, a(x) f(x) + b(x) (x^3\!-\!2) = 1,\,$ so $\, a f = 1\ $ in $\,\Bbb  Q[x]/(x^3\!-\!1) \cong \Bbb Q(\sqrt[3] 2)\ \ $ Or, by finite dimensionality, $\,w = f(x)\,$ is algebraic over $\,\Bbb Q\,$ so its inverse can be read off from its minimal polynomial $\, c+w\, g(w) = 0\,\Rightarrow w (-g(w)/c) = 1.\ \ $

Comment: See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1wSHp4U6qo&list=UU9udB3U6ZLCboZrXApr0OZA#t=2473) for a proof that if $a$ is algebraic, $F(a)=F[a]$.

Comment: Also you can use that the map $\ x \to \alpha x \ $ is $1$-$1$ so onto (being on a *finite* dim vector space), so $\,\alpha\beta = 1\,$ for some $\,\beta.\,$ No need to *calculate* $\,\det \alpha.\,$ Theory trumps calculation!

Comment: You make a $\sqrt[3]2$ by writing `\sqrt[3]{2}`. [Reference guide here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422440/does-a3-2b3-4c3-6abc-have-solutions-in-mathbbq

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume the determinant you want is
$$\det\pmatrix{p&2r&2q\cr q&p&2r\cr r&q&p\cr}=p^3+2q^3+4r^3-6pqr\ .$$
The determinant obviously is zero when $p=q=r=0$; suppose that this is not the case and the determinant is still zero, $p,q,r$ being rational.  Multiplying by a common denominator and then cancelling any common factor, we may assume that $p,q,r$ are integers with no common factor.  If
$$p^3+2q^3+4r^3-6pqr=0$$
then $2\mid p^3$ so $2\mid p$, say $p=2s$.  Substituting back and cancelling $2$ gives
$$4s^3+q^3+2r^3-6qrs=0\ .$$
This shows that $2\mid q$; then by a similar process you get $2\mid r$; this contradicts the fact that $p,q,r$ have no common factor.  Therefore the determinant cannot be zero for rational $p,q,r$, not all zero.

I am sure you can see the similarity between this proof and the standard irrationality proof for $\sqrt2\,$.

It is actually easier to do this by using the fact that $x^3-2$ is irreducible, but you asked for a determinant proof so that's what you've got ;-)

Comment: This was exactly the answer I was looking for! Thanks a lot.