# Find all positive integral solutions to the equation

Tags: number-theory

Find all positive integral solutions to the equation

$ x^3+2y^3=4z^3$

Comment: A start: $x$ is even, say $2s$. We get $4s^3+y^3=2z^3$. Go two more rounds.

Comment: Yeah it's like infinite descent

Comment: Yes, that's right, a descent argument.

Comment: Duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663985/show-that-there-exist-no-a-b-c-in-mathbb-z-such-that-a3-2b3-4c3

Answer (score 2):

$x$ is even, so if $x'=x/2$ then
$$x'^3=\frac{2z^3-y^3}{4},$$
Now $y$ is even, so
$$x'^3=\frac{z^3}{2}-2y'^3$$
Now $z$ is even and
$$x'^3+2y'^3=4z'^3$$
By the same manner we can conclude that $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$