# Embedding $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}^*$ into $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_{q})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

If we see $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$ as a $2$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ (and pick a base) then we can identify $\operatorname{Aut}_{\mathbb{F}_{q}}(\mathbb{F}_{q^2})$ with $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_{q})$. Therefore we can embed $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}^*$ into $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_{q})$, by the natural action of $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}^*$ on $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$.

However, I have difficulty to concretely visualise the subgroup $E$ of $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_{q})$ that should be congruent to $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}^*$. Is there a nice way to see this group $E$?

Comment: I wonder how you concretely visualize GL2(Fq) and Fq².

Comment: I visualise $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$ as matrices and $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$ as a $2$-dimensional vectorspace over a finite field. Instead of "concretely visualise" I might have better used "describe"

Comment: **Hint:** $\Bbb F_{q^2}^*$ is cyclic.

Comment: Are we allowed to pick the basis, or is it given?

Comment: We are allowed to pick the basis.

Comment: What's (I can't find backslash on this keyboard) what is the F_{q^2}?

Comment: The finite field with $q^2$ elements

Comment: What structure is on that ring (or is there only the one?! Isomorphic to the ring of integers mod $q^2$)

Comment: Up to isomorphism there is only one field with $q^2$ elements, where $q$ is a prime power. It is however not isomorphic to the ring of integers mod $q^2$. I have only seen the construction via a quadratic extension of the finite field of $q$ elements.

Comment: Can you embed $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ into $GL(2, \mathbb{R})$ ? Can you embed $\mathbb{C}$ into $M_{2\times 2} ( \mathbb{R})$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $q$ is odd we can do the following. Choose a non-square element $\epsilon\in \Bbb{F}_q^*\setminus (\Bbb{F}_q^*)^2.$ With respect to a suitable basis the elements of the extension field, when represented by matrices, then have the shape 
$$
\Bbb{F}_{q^2}=\left\{\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
a&b\\ \epsilon b&a
\end{array}\right)\,\bigg\vert\ a,b\in\Bbb{F}_q\right\}.
$$
The set of such matrices is easily seen to be a vector space over $\Bbb{F}_q$ and closed under multiplication. Because the determinant has the form $a^2-\epsilon b^2$, our assumption implies that it vanishes only when $a=0=b$. Hence all those matrices are invertible. Therefore they form a field of cardinality $q^2$.

This is particularly simple in the case $q\equiv 3\pmod 4$, because we can then choose $\epsilon=-1$ and end up with the analogue of the familiar representation of complex numbers as $2\times2$ real matrices. The reason for this similarity is, of course, that we use the construction
$$
\Bbb{F}_{q^2}=\Bbb{F}_q[\sqrt\epsilon].
$$

When $q$ is even there are similar ways, but they are not so "clean". If $a\in \Bbb{F}_q$ is such that its absolute trace is $=1$ (i.e. does not vanish), then the polynomial $p(x)=x^2+x+a$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{F}_q[x]$, and we can pick a basis $\{1,\alpha\}$, where $\alpha$ is a zero of $p(x)$.

Comment: Out of curiosity, could we also use this type of approach to embed $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}^*$ into $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$?

Comment: Whenever the extension can be gotten by adjoining an $n$th root of an element of $\Bbb{F}_q$ it looks about as simple as this. See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/700923/11619) for an example with $n=3, q=13$. In general we cannot get the extension by adjoining an $n$th root, and it becomes a little bit messier.

Answer (score 2):

It might not be a fully satisfactory description.

Note that the subgroup $E\le GL_2(\Bbb F_q)$ varies according to the choice of the basis.

---

Knowing that the multiplicative group of any finite field is cyclic, choose a generator $\alpha$ of $\Bbb F_{q^2}$, and pick the following basis of $\Bbb F_{q^2}$ over $\Bbb F_q$:
$$(1,\,\alpha)$$
Then the linear mapping $x\mapsto \alpha\cdot x$ becomes the matrix $M$ with columns $(\alpha,\alpha^2)$.
[Note that $\alpha=\pmatrix{0\\1}$ in our chosen basis.]

and $E$ will consist of all the powers of $M$.

Comment: Would it then be right to visualise $E$ as the matrices $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ \alpha^{n} & \alpha^{n+1} \end{pmatrix}$ where $0 \leq n < q^2-1$?

Comment: @Krijn: Something is wrong in your thinking? The non-zero elements of a field are invertible, so those matrices should have non-zero determinants. Also, their entries are in the smaller field. So Berci needs to use the minimal polynomial (it's a quadratic) to write $\alpha^2$ as a linear combination of $1$ and $\alpha$.

Comment: Ah, so if we would write $\alpha^2 = a + b\cdot \alpha$ then we could write $E$ as the matrix group generated by $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a \\  1 & b \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: Correct, @Krijn.