# Q($\sqrt[3]{2}$) - Unique Factorisation Domain?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, unique-factorization-domains

I am considering the set of "integers" of the from

$$ a+b\sqrt[3]{2} + c\sqrt[3]{4} $$

where $a,b,c$ are integers. It is easy to show this field is closed under addition and multiplication. I then wish to determine whether Unique Factorisation holds for these integers. Motivated by other examples such as the Gaussian Integers and the Eisenstein Integers, I attempt to define a norm for these integers such that $ N(ab) = N(a)*N(b) $ and the norm always an integer, to then show the field is Euclidean and hence a Unique Factorisation Domain. However, here I get stuck. Unlike the Gaussian and Eisenstein integers, I cannot see how to define the Norm for this field.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a product of three factors, since $\sqrt[3]{2}$ has three conjugates [in the splitting field of $X^3-2$], namely $\sqrt[3]{2}, \omega\sqrt[3]{2},\omega^2\sqrt[3]{2}$, where $\omega = \exp \frac{2\pi i}{3}$.

Comment: The general recipe for a multiplicative norm goes as follows. View multiplication by $x=a+b\root3\of2+c\root3\of4$ as a $\Bbb{Q}$-linear mapping.$\rho(x)$. Let $M(x)$ ne matrix of $\rho(x)$ in terms of the basis $\{1,\root3\of2,\root3\of4\}$. Then define $N(x)=\det M(x)$.

Comment: Daniel Fischer, could you elaborate on your comment?

Comment: I've forgotten too many details to be sure that I wouldn't say something wrong, so I defer to Jyrki's comment. The basic fact is that the complex eigenvalues of $M(x)$ are then $a + b\sqrt[3]{2} + c\sqrt[3]{4},\, a + \omega b\sqrt[3]{2} + \omega^2 c\sqrt[3]{4}$, and $a + \omega^2 b\sqrt[3]{2} + \omega c \sqrt[3]{4}$, the latter two being the conjugates of the first.

Comment: Never mind, and thank you for your first comment. I solved it thanks to it. I just multiplied three integers, each one a permutation of the three roots of unity. I obtained the following as the norm: $ a^3+2b^3+4c^3-6abc $

Comment: The term you're looking for is "algebraic integers." Alaca-Williams *IANT* shows this to be UFD but the proof requires understanding almost everything in the preceding 300 pages, and instead of saying it's UFD they say that "the class number is trivial."

Comment: Which you can generalize to $a^3 + b^3 d + c^3 d^2 − 3abcd$.

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329936/primes-represented-integrally-by-a-homogeneous-cubic-form

Comment: What you've described is not a field, it's just a ring, namely $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$. The field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is its field of fractions. I think using norms does not work.

Answer (score 2):

make this CW;

the result mentioned by Robert Soupe is page 327, Example 12.6.9,  *Introductory Algebraic Number Theory* by Alaca and Williams, [http://www.amazon.com/Introductory-Algebraic-Number-Theory-Saban/dp/0521540119](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521540119)

See [primes represented integrally by a homogeneous cubic form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329936/primes-represented-integrally-by-a-homogeneous-cubic-form)

The part that was done entirely was class number one, (rational) primes $q \equiv 2 \pmod 3,$ also $p = u^2 + 27 v^2.$

My belief, with calculation done for a different norm form, is that when $q = 4 u^2 +2uv+7v^2,$ with integers $u,v$ (not necessarily positive), whenever we have
$$ a^3 + 2 b^3 + 4 c^3 - 6abc \equiv 0 \pmod q,  $$
THEN
$$ a,b,c \equiv 0 \pmod q.  $$
The first few such primes are
$$      7,     13,     19,     37,     61,     67,     73,     79,     97,    103,
    139,    151,    163,    181,    193,    199, $$
NOTE: This has been confirmed by Noam Elkies. Also note that these are precisely the primes for which there is no cube root of $2.$

I actually have the IANT book somewhere, I will check. Meanwhile, a complete proof for everything for a different norm form is at  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127160/numbers-integrally-represented-by-a-ternary-cubic-form