# Generalizing the growth of sums of two squares

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, diophantine-equations, analytic-combinatorics

Consider the set $S$ of numbers which are the sum of two (integer) squares, and define $S(n)$ as the number of members of $S$ in $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}.$ It is well-known that
$$
S(n) \sim \frac{Kn}{\sqrt{\log n}}
$$
with a constant $K$ (0.7642..., called the Landau-Ramanujan constant).

Sums of two squares can be characterized as numbers of the form $ab^2$ where $a$ is a product of distinct primes $\equiv\{1,2\}\pmod4.$ I expect that any modulus $m$ and any subset $T\subseteq\{0,1,\ldots,m-1\}$ containing $0<t<\varphi(m)$ elements coprime to $m$ would have similar growth:
$$
T(n) \sim \frac{Cn}{\sqrt{\log n}}
$$
for some constant $C>0$ depending on $m$ and $T$. Is this true? Perhaps the denominator needs to be $(\log n)^d$ for some $d$ depending on $m$ and $T$ as well?

Edit: I would settle for the (simpler?) case where $b=1$.

Comment: You get the same outcome for numbers represented by at least one quadratic form of a fixed discriminant. Also primitively represented. I don't see this working for, say, norm forms for cubic fields http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329936/primes-represented-integrally-by-a-homogeneous-cubic-form

Comment: Alright, I started to become uncertain after i typed the answer, so i left it for your comment.

Comment: I don't quite follow the statement: if the set $T$ depends on $n$, how can you have an asymptotic in $n$ that depends on $T$?  Similarly what is $m$ in the definition of $T$?

Comment: if you're just asking about the distribution of sums of squares in a fixed residue class, I believe that was studied by Hooley.

Comment: @ErickWong Sorry for the unintentional variable clash. Replace $mn^2$ with $ab^2$.

Comment: @Charles Ok thanks, so I assume the $n-1$ should be an $m-1$ and then the question is just about distribution in residue classes.  It also seems like you want to still restrict $m$ in some way: if $m=4$ and $T = \{3\}$ then the counting function is $0$.

Comment: @ErickWong: I've edited the question. If $m=4$ and $T=\{3\}$ then $T(n)$ counts numbers which are squarefree products of primes for the form $4k+3$ multiplied by arbitrary squares: 1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 11, 12, 16, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 28, 31, 33, 36, 43, 44, 47, 48, 49, 57, 59, etc.

Comment: @Charles Ahhh now I get it.  Yes, I think in many cases such an asymptotic is achievable via Selberg-Delange or Wirsing-Odoni.  As you guessed, the exponent will be something like $1-t/\phi(m)$ instead of $1/2$.