# A homogeneous cubic polynomial with no non-trivial zero over $\mathbf{F_7}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry

I met a problem in class which I cannot solve:

> Find a homogeneous cubic polynomial of three variables $x, y, z$ that has no non-trivial zero over $\mathbf{F_7}$.

Homogeneous cubic polynomial means each monomial term of the polynomial has degree 3. I do not have many thoughts and just attempted with trials but did not have any right candidate. I know the third power of any element in $\mathbf{F_7}$ is $\pm 1$ or $0$ so I tried to consider the sum of three cubic elements like $(x-y)^3+(x+z)^3+(y+z)^3$ but none of them worked. Is there any systematic way to approach it? Any hint or thought is appreciated!

Comment: What is the definition of homogeneous?

Comment: "I know the third power of any element in $\textrm{F}_7$ is $\pm 1$" or zero.

Comment: Shouldn't such a polynomial always have solution $(0,0,0)$. Do you want a nonzero solution?

Comment: Yes, I edited the problem. The problem is from an introductory level class on algebraic geometry so it is under the context of projective space and thus non-trivial solution. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: You're right. Just deleted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + xyz + xy^2 + 4yz^2 + 2 z x^2 $$

indeed, of the 343 triples $(x,y,z),$ only when we have $(0,0,0)$ is the polynomial equal to $0 \pmod 7.$ Each of the other six values mod 7 is represented 57 times,  and $6 \cdot 57 = 342$

Comment: Yes it works! Could you please tell me how do you see the other six values is represented 57 times, or how do you approach the problem generally?

Comment: How did you find this? Is there any better search method than just brute force?

Comment: This might be a norm form: take a cubic extension $K\supset k$, with basis $\{u,v,w\}$, and look at the $\text{Norm}^K_k(xu+yv+zw)$, where $x,y,z$ are thought of as in $k$. Then you get a degree-$3$ homogeneous polynomial in the three letters $x,y,z$, which never vanishes when the corresponding element of $K$ is nonzero.

Comment: @Lubin thanks. I'll see if I can write it in matrices...

Comment: @Lubin's comment is spot on. If the cubic is nonsingular, it defines a genus $1$ curve over $\mathbf{F}_7$ which then automatically has a point over $\mathbf{F}_7$.  If it is geometrically connected singular cubic then it has a unique singular point which is then defined over $\mathbf{F}_7$. Hence it is not geometrically connected. If there is a single linear factor the factors are over $\mathbf{F}_7$ and have points, so it must be three lines which are permuted by Galois, thus a multiple of a norm form, and such a form also gives an example.

Comment: The classic norm form would be $N((x+ 2^{1/3}y+2^{2/3} z) =x^3 + 2y^3 + 4z^3- 6 xyz$. Since $\mathbf{F}_7(2^{1/3}) = \mathbf{F}_{343}$ this also gives an example. As there is a unique cubic extension of $\mathbf{F}_7$, your example must be $\mathrm{PGL}_3(\mathbf{F}_{343})$ equivalent to this one.

Comment: @Lubin   does it suffice to take a monic irreducible cubic (mod 7) let $M$ be the companion matrix for the polynomial $t^3 + a t^2 + bt + c, $ finally letting the homogeneous polynomial the determinant of $xI + y M + z M^2 \; \; ?  \; \;$

Comment: Yes, @WillJagy , that seems to be precisely what I do to calculate a norm form.

Comment: @Lubin thank you. I have asked about a few such forms over the years, here is an MO question where Noam Elkies  answered, also (it seems) confirming the companion matrix part. I eventually edited out the part where someone I asked at MSRI laughed at me, but that still appears in Noam's answer.    https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127160/numbers-integrally-represented-by-a-ternary-cubic-form

Comment: @KReiser I put a new answer with a clear procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Note: the answer recommended by user760870 is something I asked about years ago, at [primes represented integrally by a homogeneous cubic form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329936/primes-represented-integrally-by-a-homogeneous-cubic-form)

Alright; this is what they wanted us to figure out. Take a polynomial in one variable that is irreducible over the field, I choose
$$  x^3 - 3 x -1  $$

Next, make the 3 by 3 matrix that is the companion matrix for the polynomial.

$$
M =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 3 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Finally, take the matrix
$$ xI + yM + z M^2  $$

to get the norm form

$$ \det (xI +yM +z M^2)= \color{red}{ x^3 + y^3 + z^3 -3xyz  -3yz^2 +6z x^2 -3xy^2 + 9 z^2 x } $$

COMPUTER CAUTION: if using integers on a computer, it is not enough to command   t % 7, since the t resulting from the cubic above may be negative, ans t % 7 may be a number from $-6$ to $0.$ My variable was named sump, I was getting wrong totals until I put in

```
 sump %=7;

sump += 7;

sump %=7;
```

...........................................

```
? factormod( x^3 - 3*x-1,7)
%35 = 
[Mod(1, 7)*x^3 + Mod(4, 7)*x + Mod(6, 7) 1]


    ? 
    ? mat = [ 0,1,0; 0,0,1; 1,3,0]
    %31 = 
    [0 1 0]

    [0 0 1]

    [1 3 0]

    ? charpoly(mat)
    %32 = x^3 - 3*x - 1
    ? d = x* matid(3) + y * mat + z * mat^2
    %33 = 
    [x       y       z]

    [z x + 3*z       y]

    [y 3*y + z x + 3*z]

    ? normform2 = matdet(d)
    %34 = x^3 + 6*z*x^2 + (-3*y^2 - 3*z*y + 9*z^2)*x + (y^3 - 3*z^2*y + z^3)
    ?
```

..........

Comment: The example I gave in my comments (with $(t^3 - 2)$) is prettier since it has such a compact norm form with only four terms. Alternatively, you could just factor the example *you* originally gave: the polynomial $t^3 + t - 1$ is irreducible over $\mathbf{F}_7$. If

$$M = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 & 0 \end{matrix}\right) \in M_3(\mathbf{F}_7)$$

then $I,M,M^{12}$ are linearly independent (even if not a power basis), and then

$$\mathrm{det}(x I + y M + z M^{12} ) =  x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + xyz + xy^2 + 4yz^2 + 2 z x^2$$

recovers your example.

Comment: @user760870  excellent. Among other things, I could not see how to recover my original example, nor what might be reasonable conditions for perturbing my simple  construction.