# Prove that $a^3 + 2b^3 + 4c^3 − 6abc \neq 0$ if at least one of $a$, $b$, and $c$ are non-zero

Tags: linear-algebra, arithmetic

Prove for $a, b, c \in \mathbb Q$ that $a^3 + 2b^3 + 4c^3 − 6abc \neq 0$ if at least one of $a$, $b$, and $c$ are non-zero without resorting to field theory or linear algebra.

Comment: Are $a,b,c$ restricted to being integers?

Comment: Do you have a linear algebra/field theory solution that you don't like?

Comment: Let's not forget that the cubes of negative numbers are also negative, making this question much more interesting than I thought at first.

Comment: Please use the symbol \$ to enclose all the mathematical contents, and please specify what objects  $a, b, c$ are. For example, if $a, b, c$ are not real numbers then the proposition gets meaningless.

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/327884/show-determinant-of-matrix-is-non-zero

Comment: I've added the restrictions on a, b and c: they have to be rational.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proof is by descent. It is obvious that if one of the variables is $0$, then they must all be.  So we can assume all the variables are non-zero.

Because of the homogeneity, if there is a non-zero rational solution, then   there is a non-zero integer solution.  Then there is such a solution with $|a|+|b|+|c|$ *minimal*.

It is clear that $a$ is even. Let $a=2q$. Substituting, we get that 
$$2b^3+4c^3+8q^3 -12bcq=0,$$ or equivalently
$$b^3+2c^3+4q^3-6bcq=0.$$
But $|b|+|c|+|q|\lt |a|+|b|+|c|$,
contradicting the minimality of $|a|+|b|+|c|$.

Comment: That is a very short and sweet answer, thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. Descent aka induction is a nice tool. Thank you, Fermat!

Comment: You assume that $a$ is non-zero in the proof. What happens if we use the weaker restriction that not all three of $a$, $b$, and $c$ are zero?

Comment: That is not interesting. If one of the variables is $0$, then $6abc=0$, and we are looking at $a^3+2b^3=0$ or $a^3+4c^3=0$ or $2b^3+4c^3=0$, none of which have solutions since $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is irrational.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. The $1,2,4$ and even coefficient for $abc$ made descent irresistible.

Answer (score 0):

For any prime $q = 4 u^2 + 2 u v + 7 v^2$ in integers, the polynomial 
$ a^3 + 2b^3 + 4c^3 − 6abc  $ is only divisible by $q$ when $a,b,c$ are **all** divisible by $q.$ The first few primes that could be used here are 
   $$ 7,13,19,37,61,67,73,79,97,103,139,151,163,181$$

If there is any nontrivial solution, in integers, to $ a^3 + 2b^3 + 4c^3 − 6abc =0, $ we can divide out any common factor to get another solution with $\gcd(a,b,c) = 1.$

Put these two together, there is no nontrivial solution. Below are the 343 calculations of $n \equiv a^3 + 2b^3 + 4c^3 − 6abc \pmod 7.$ You can see that the only occurrence of $n \equiv 0 \pmod 7 $ is $a \equiv b \equiv c \equiv 0 \pmod 7.$

```
 n        a        b        c  
 0        0        0        0
 1        0        3        3
 1        0        3        5
 1        0        3        6
 1        0        5        3
 1        0        5        5
 1        0        5        6
 1        0        6        3
 1        0        6        5
 1        0        6        6
 1        1        0        0
 1        1        1        1
 1        1        2        4
 1        1        3        4
 1        1        4        2
 1        1        5        1
 1        1        6        2
 1        2        0        0
 1        2        1        4
 1        2        2        2
 1        2        3        2
 1        2        4        1
 1        2        5        4
 1        2        6        1
 1        3        1        0
 1        3        1        1
 1        3        1        6
 1        3        2        0
 1        3        2        3
 1        3        2        4
 1        3        4        0
 1        3        4        2
 1        3        4        5
 1        4        0        0
 1        4        1        2
 1        4        2        1
 1        4        3        1
 1        4        4        4
 1        4        5        2
 1        4        6        4
 1        5        1        0
 1        5        1        2
 1        5        1        5
 1        5        2        0
 1        5        2        1
 1        5        2        6
 1        5        4        0
 1        5        4        3
 1        5        4        4
 1        6        1        0
 1        6        1        3
 1        6        1        4
 1        6        2        0
 1        6        2        2
 1        6        2        5
 1        6        4        0
 1        6        4        1
 1        6        4        6
 2        0        1        0
 2        0        2        0
 2        0        3        1
 2        0        3        2
 2        0        3        4
 2        0        4        0
 2        0        5        1
 2        0        5        2
 2        0        5        4
 2        0        6        1
 2        0        6        2
 2        0        6        4
 2        1        1        2
 2        1        1        3
 2        1        2        1
 2        1        2        5
 2        1        3        2
 2        1        4        4
 2        1        4        6
 2        1        5        4
 2        1        6        1
 2        2        1        1
 2        2        1        5
 2        2        2        4
 2        2        2        6
 2        2        3        1
 2        2        4        2
 2        2        4        3
 2        2        5        2
 2        2        6        4
 2        3        0        3
 2        3        0        5
 2        3        0        6
 2        3        3        4
 2        3        5        1
 2        3        6        2
 2        4        1        4
 2        4        1        6
 2        4        2        2
 2        4        2        3
 2        4        3        4
 2        4        4        1
 2        4        4        5
 2        4        5        1
 2        4        6        2
 2        5        0        3
 2        5        0        5
 2        5        0        6
 2        5        3        1
 2        5        5        2
 2        5        6        4
 2        6        0        3
 2        6        0        5
 2        6        0        6
 2        6        3        2
 2        6        5        4
 2        6        6        1
 3        0        0        3
 3        0        0        5
 3        0        0        6
 3        1        1        0
 3        1        2        0
 3        1        3        5
 3        1        4        0
 3        1        5        3
 3        1        6        6
 3        2        1        0
 3        2        2        0
 3        2        3        6
 3        2        4        0
 3        2        5        5
 3        2        6        3
 3        3        0        1
 3        3        0        2
 3        3        0        4
 3        3        1        4
 3        3        2        2
 3        3        3        1
 3        3        3        5
 3        3        4        1
 3        3        5        2
 3        3        5        3
 3        3        6        4
 3        3        6        6
 3        4        1        0
 3        4        2        0
 3        4        3        3
 3        4        4        0
 3        4        5        6
 3        4        6        5
 3        5        0        1
 3        5        0        2
 3        5        0        4
 3        5        1        1
 3        5        2        4
 3        5        3        2
 3        5        3        3
 3        5        4        2
 3        5        5        4
 3        5        5        6
 3        5        6        1
 3        5        6        5
 3        6        0        1
 3        6        0        2
 3        6        0        4
 3        6        1        2
 3        6        2        1
 3        6        3        4
 3        6        3        6
 3        6        4        4
 3        6        5        1
 3        6        5        5
 3        6        6        2
 3        6        6        3
 4        0        0        1
 4        0        0        2
 4        0        0        4
 4        1        0        3
 4        1        0        5
 4        1        0        6
 4        1        1        4
 4        1        1        5
 4        1        2        2
 4        1        2        6
 4        1        3        3
 4        1        4        1
 4        1        4        3
 4        1        5        6
 4        1        6        5
 4        2        0        3
 4        2        0        5
 4        2        0        6
 4        2        1        2
 4        2        1        6
 4        2        2        1
 4        2        2        3
 4        2        3        5
 4        2        4        4
 4        2        4        5
 4        2        5        3
 4        2        6        6
 4        3        1        2
 4        3        2        1
 4        3        3        0
 4        3        4        4
 4        3        5        0
 4        3        6        0
 4        4        0        3
 4        4        0        5
 4        4        0        6
 4        4        1        1
 4        4        1        3
 4        4        2        4
 4        4        2        5
 4        4        3        6
 4        4        4        2
 4        4        4        6
 4        4        5        5
 4        4        6        3
 4        5        1        4
 4        5        2        2
 4        5        3        0
 4        5        4        1
 4        5        5        0
 4        5        6        0
 4        6        1        1
 4        6        2        4
 4        6        3        0
 4        6        4        2
 4        6        5        0
 4        6        6        0
 5        0        1        3
 5        0        1        5
 5        0        1        6
 5        0        2        3
 5        0        2        5
 5        0        2        6
 5        0        3        0
 5        0        4        3
 5        0        4        5
 5        0        4        6
 5        0        5        0
 5        0        6        0
 5        1        0        1
 5        1        0        2
 5        1        0        4
 5        1        1        6
 5        1        2        3
 5        1        4        5
 5        2        0        1
 5        2        0        2
 5        2        0        4
 5        2        1        3
 5        2        2        5
 5        2        4        6
 5        3        1        5
 5        3        2        6
 5        3        3        2
 5        3        3        6
 5        3        4        3
 5        3        5        4
 5        3        5        5
 5        3        6        1
 5        3        6        3
 5        4        0        1
 5        4        0        2
 5        4        0        4
 5        4        1        5
 5        4        2        6
 5        4        4        3
 5        5        1        3
 5        5        2        5
 5        5        3        4
 5        5        3        5
 5        5        4        6
 5        5        5        1
 5        5        5        3
 5        5        6        2
 5        5        6        6
 5        6        1        6
 5        6        2        3
 5        6        3        1
 5        6        3        3
 5        6        4        5
 5        6        5        2
 5        6        5        6
 5        6        6        4
 5        6        6        5
 6        0        1        1
 6        0        1        2
 6        0        1        4
 6        0        2        1
 6        0        2        2
 6        0        2        4
 6        0        4        1
 6        0        4        2
 6        0        4        4
 6        1        3        0
 6        1        3        1
 6        1        3        6
 6        1        5        0
 6        1        5        2
 6        1        5        5
 6        1        6        0
 6        1        6        3
 6        1        6        4
 6        2        3        0
 6        2        3        3
 6        2        3        4
 6        2        5        0
 6        2        5        1
 6        2        5        6
 6        2        6        0
 6        2        6        2
 6        2        6        5
 6        3        0        0
 6        3        1        3
 6        3        2        5
 6        3        3        3
 6        3        4        6
 6        3        5        6
 6        3        6        5
 6        4        3        0
 6        4        3        2
 6        4        3        5
 6        4        5        0
 6        4        5        3
 6        4        5        4
 6        4        6        0
 6        4        6        1
 6        4        6        6
 6        5        0        0
 6        5        1        6
 6        5        2        3
 6        5        3        6
 6        5        4        5
 6        5        5        5
 6        5        6        3
 6        6        0        0
 6        6        1        5
 6        6        2        6
 6        6        3        5
 6        6        4        3
 6        6        5        3
 6        6        6        6
```

---