# Show that the determinant of a matrix is nonzero

Tags: matrices, number-theory, determinant

> Suppose $u,v,w \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $u,v,w \neq 0$. Show that the
> determinant of the following matrix is nonzero.
> $$M = \begin{bmatrix} u & 2w & 2v \\ v & u & 2w \\ w & v & u \end{bmatrix}$$
> *Hint:* Argue by contradiction, reduce to the case when $u,v,w$ are integers and use some number theory over $\mathbb{Z}$.

I know that the determinant is given by
$$ \det M = u^{3} + 2v^{3} + 4w^{3} - 6 \,u\,v\,w $$

It is unclear to me how to utilize the hint. How to convert the problem over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: See the answer by EuYu. Moreover, also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/888707/prove-that-a3-2b3-4c3-%E2%88%92-6abc-neq-0-if-at-least-one-of-a-b-and-c?noredirect=1&lq=1) gives a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As $u,v,w$ are rationals, you can just multiply every entry with a sufficiently large integer so that every entry becomes an integer. This will not change the fact whether the determinant is zero or not. Therefore, w.l.o.g. $u,v,w$ can be assumed to be integers. Similarly, we can assume that $u,v,w$ are not all even (otherwise just divide all entries by $2$ and repeat). Now observe that if $\det M = 0$, then $u$ must be even. But that means that $u^3+4w^3-6uvw = -2v^3$ is divisible by $4$. Hence $v$ is even, too. Thus $u^3+2v^3-6uvw = -4w^3$ is divisible by $8$, and so $w$ is even as well. Contradiction.